# Running parallel pipelines on different branches

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

These are two branches of a project www.example.com: **branch logan and branch bella**.

The 33rd pipeline is the logan branch of www.example.com, and the 34rd pipeline is the bella branch of www.example.com.

**When the 33rd pipeline is not over, the 34rd pepeline will always be in the pending stage.**

If the pepeline of one branch is pending, the pepeline of the other branch will be affected?
This is very strange.How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: do you have your own runners? if so try modifying their concurrence

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own runners, you can modify the `config.toml` file, specifically changing the `request_concurrency` property:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "super-runner"
  request_concurrency = 10
  ...
```

If using `kubernetes` executor you can add the env variable `RUNNER_REQUEST_CONCURRENCY` and it will set the desired `request_concurrency` for every runner created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.